# R - Calculate Observations Elapsed Since Last Event with Multiple Event Types and IDs

Tags: r, datatable

I am wondering how to calculate the number of observations since the same type of event but also to find the number of observations since any other type of event. I also have ids in my datatable.

To illustrate, please see below. I am trying to do this in R using Datatables but to little result.

What I have is a datatable as follows:

```
  date     event  id
2000-07-06     2  1
2000-07-07     1  1
2000-07-09     0  1
2000-07-10     0  1
2000-07-15     2  1
2000-07-16     1  1
2000-07-20     0  1
2000-07-21     1  1
2000-07-06     1  2
2000-07-07     2  2
2000-07-15     0  2
2000-07-16     0  2
2000-07-17     2  2
2000-07-18     1  2
```

and what I would like to have is something like this:

```
  date     event  id obs_since_event_1 obs_since_event_2
2000-07-06     2  1        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     1  1        NA                 1
2000-07-09     0  1        1                  2
2000-07-10     0  1        2                  3
2000-07-15     2  1        3                  4
2000-07-16     1  1        4                  1
2000-07-20     0  1        1                  2
2000-07-21     1  1        2                  3
2000-07-06     1  2        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     2  2        1                  NA
2000-07-15     0  2        2                  1
2000-07-16     0  2        3                  2
2000-07-17     2  2        4                  3
2000-07-18     1  2        5                  1
```

The two events are mutually exclusive, that is, they cannot take place on the same observed day. Hope to hear some good advice. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this using `dplyr` and non-standard evaluation :

```
library(dplyr)

apply_fun <- function(df, value) {

  col <- paste0('obs_since_event_', value)
  df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    group_by(temp = lag(cumsum(event == value), default = 0), add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(!!col := row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(!!col := replace(!!sym(col), temp == 0, NA))  %>%
    select(-temp)
}

df <- apply_fun(df, 1)
df <- apply_fun(df, 2)

df

# A tibble: 14 x 5
#   date       event    id obs_since_event_1 obs_since_event_2
#   <fct>      <int> <int>             <int>             <int>
# 1 2000-07-06     2     1                NA                NA
# 2 2000-07-07     1     1                NA                 1
# 3 2000-07-09     0     1                 1                 2
# 4 2000-07-10     0     1                 2                 3
# 5 2000-07-15     2     1                 3                 4
# 6 2000-07-16     1     1                 4                 1
# 7 2000-07-20     0     1                 1                 2
# 8 2000-07-21     1     1                 2                 3
# 9 2000-07-06     1     2                NA                NA
#10 2000-07-07     2     2                 1                NA
#11 2000-07-15     0     2                 2                 1
#12 2000-07-16     0     2                 3                 2
#13 2000-07-17     2     2                 4                 3
#14 2000-07-18     1     2                 5                 1
```

Comment: Hi Ronak! 
This apparently does not work. When running your code the counter does not reset. It simply counts upwards

Comment: @Rnovice I am not sure what might be wrong. It works for the sample data that you have provided so I have no way to verify what you are saying.